# tikz in math environment: unrecoverable errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

When I run

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\ema}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}\xspace}

\newcommand{\defas}{
\ema{\mathop{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetbaseline{-.4ex}
\fill (-1.2ex,.4ex) circle (.5pt); 
\fill (-1.2ex,-.05ex) circle (.5pt); 
\draw[] (-.76ex,.4ex) -- (0.0ex,.4ex);
\draw[] (-.76ex,-.05ex) -- (0.0ex,-.05ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
}} }

\begin{document}

The $\defas$ does not work.

\end{document}
```

I  get the error

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the matht cause unrecoverable errors.
```

However, on a different machine it does work. Both are Linux machines using pdflatex. What could that be?

It works on version `pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)` but not on version `3.0.1 a`

Comment: Different versions of TikZ/PGF? By the way, what's the purpose of `\xspace`? In that position it can only give problems, or otherwise do nothing sensible.

Comment: And what's wrong with `\coloneq` provided by `mathtools`?

Comment: `\pgfversion` should print the version number of `pgf`/TikZ, so you can compare that for your two machines. (`\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\pgfversion\end{document}`)

Comment: @egreg: `\coloneq`'s points are further apart then the = lines.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.:  It works on version `pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)` but not on version `3.0.1 a`

Comment: Works for me with 3.0.1a

Comment: Works fine with 3.0.1a here as well.